# How to write data to a process/memory?

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, console, offset

Okay so I'm making a basic Win32 console application that can read but more importantly write to a process's memory. Like it attaches onto a process/.exe

So say I have a pointer and an offset, how would I go about writing data to the pointer/offset?

So like for example the dynamic address is 00A89BCA. Pointer is 0x00EBCDB08 and Offset is 0xBCD7

I would like to write an integer value to this address.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Does the process that you are writing to know that you are doing this?  The scope for mayhem is **HUGE**.  If this is a cooperative effort (both processes are aware) I'd suggest trying a memory mapped file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912215.aspx) - which isn't (necessarily) really a file.  It is way safer.

Answer (score 6):

`OpenProcess` -> [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)